# PHP object cannot find method

Tags: php, oop

So I have a very simple class that has a method called getThumbUrl() but when I try calling this method on an instance I get

Notice: Undefined property: FlickrImage::$getThumbUrl

But it is clearly there. Here is the code of the function inside of the FlickrImage class:

```
public function getThumbUrl()
{
    return "http://farm".$this->_farm.".static.flickr.com/".$this->_server."/".$this->_id."_".$this->_secret."_t.jpg";
}
```

And here is where it fails inside of a different testing file:

```
$flickrTester = new FlickrManager();

$photos = $flickrTester->getPhotoStreamImages(9, 1);

foreach($photos as $photo) {
    echo "<img src='$photo->getThumbUrl()' />";
}
```

Comment: Hate to break it to you, but your foreach is calling $photo->getFullUrl(), but the function/method you posted is getThumbUrl(). Typo?

Comment: Sorry! that function exists too though

Comment: Can you provide some more code? How you get the images etc. From what you posted it is difficult to help.

Comment: I added a little more. The testing code is in a different file. And the getPhotoStreamImages method returns an array of FlickrPhotos. I did a var_dump and they are def in the array

Comment: Looks like if i take the function call out of the <img> element then it works. Can you not call object method from inside strings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add curly-braces around the `$photo->getThumbUrl()` in your echo.  Here's whats going on.  Without surrounding the method in curly-braces PHP will try to resolve `$photo->getThumbUrl` and will treat the `()` as plain text.  The error that you're seeing then is PHP complaining that `$photo->getThumbUrl` hasn't been declared, as indeed it hasn't.

```
foreach($photos as $photo) {
    echo "<img src='{$photo->getThumbUrl()}' />";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From what you say, you are calling it like:

```
FlickrImage::$getFullUrl
```

Rather than:

```
FlickrImage::$getFullUrl()
```

So you are missing `()` at the end.

```
foreach($photos as $photo) {
    echo '<img src="' . $photo->getThumbUrl() . '" />';
}
```